# Second monitor connected with Windows 10 laptop

Tags: laptop, display

Hi I have a aver aspire laptop that has Windows 10 installed. I have a problem with using the second monitor for my laptop because it only allows me to use the second monitor when I duplicate but not when u want to use the second montor only. Also when I do use the second montor with duplicate screen mode then the colours are weird and it isn't sharp. I never had this problem when I had window 8.1. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear as to what you want to do, but there's a way to do everything, so here goes:

1. Have Monitor 1 and Monitor 2 show the exact same desktop:
   [image: duplicate]
2. Have one desktop that spans across both Monitor 1 *and* Monitor 2:
   [image: extend]
3. Show desktop only on Monitor 1:
   [image: monitor1]
4. Show desktop only on Monitor 2:
   [image: monitor2]

As for weird colors and a fuzzy display, that sounds like you need to calibrate the display.  This varies between display manufacturers, but try resetting your display to its factory default settings.

Comment: And for some reason my screenshots aren't showing up...  Stand by...

Comment: OK, links to pictures have been posted.  Anyone who can edit to embed the pictures, please do.